# get specific string from json data using jq

Tags: json, jq

I only want `with` from the sample file below.

This is just for refernece, cannot paste company code here as it runs on secured environment so not allowed but my problem is somewhat similar. I have to get a specific string form the value.
Please help

```json
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "**Chocolate with Sprinkles**" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your current query, maybe you're almost there ...

Comment: Only the word `with`?? Could you say something more please? For example, do you want the second space-delimited string in the `type` value corresponding to `id` 5006 in the `topping` array?  To just get the word `with`, you'd do `echo with`.

Comment: `jq -r '.topping[]|select(.id=="5006").type/" "|.[1]'`?

Comment: yeah I tried this and got this but I want only with as an output.

Comment: What is your query? Do you, for example, know that you're looking for something in `topping`? Do you have the `id` number? Do you know that you want the word `with` or do you just want the second word? Do you even know that you are looking for something in a `type` value?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas gave the answer here but what i am looking for is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
jq -r '.topping[] | select(.id == "5006").type / " " | .[1]' file.json
```

This selects the array element in the `topping` array that has an `id` equal to the string `5006`, and extracts value of the `type` key from that.  It then splits that value on spaces and extracts the second generated word.  This is outputted, decoded, on to standard output.

If `/ " "` looks funny, you may replace that part with `| split(" ")`, which is more explicit in what it does. Or `| scan("\\S+")` to extract the sequences of non-whitespace characters in case there are leading or trailing spaces in the string, or other whitespace characters than space or more than one whitespace character between words.

If you are unsure *where* in your document that string is, but that it's the `type` value of an object with and `id` equal to the string `5006`, then you may use

```bsh
jq -r '.. | select(.id? == "5006").type / " " | .[1]' file.json
```

This iterates over all values and keys (and is therefore very inefficient) and selects anything that has a key `id` with value `5006`.  It then proceeds just like the topmost variation above.

Either expression yields the word `with` on standard output, given the data in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't provided what information you know, such as the names of keys etc but here is my best guess if you allow using cut as well:

`cat testjq.json | jq -r '.topping[] | select(.id == "5006" )' | grep type | cut -d "\"" -f 4 | cut -d " " -f 2`

Comment: There is no reason not to continue the `jq` expression to extract the `type` etc.

Comment: You're right. I just didn't know the remainder of the jq syntax so I gave what I knew.